# Binary digit display structure

Tags: c++

I am doing a larger project independently, so I wish to make sure that my prior code is stable and that it will not make any issues along the way.

I have several basic uses for this code:
 - **Display bits**
 - **Allow public access to individual bits**
 - **Allow from `integer` conversion (truncate larger `ints`)**
 - **Allow to `integer` conversion**

### Here is the code:

*Structure definition `hpp`*

```cpp
#include <iostream>

struct bin_data{

    bool b0:1,b1:1,b2:1,b3:1,b4:1,b5:1,b6:1,b7:1;

    bin_data(int);                                  // initialiser

    bin_data( const bin_data &bdat );               // copy constructor
    bin_data( bin_data && bdat );                   // move constructor
    //bin_data( nabu );                             // this part is dependent on different struct
    // I decided to show that, but omit the code since then dependency will be too long

    bin_data& operator=( const bin_data &bdat );    // copy asigment
    bin_data& operator=( bin_data && bdat );        // move asigment

    ~bin_data();                                    // deconstructor
    operator bool()
    { return this->b0 | this->b1 | this->b2 | this->b3 | this->b4 | this->b5 | this->b6 | this->b7; }

    operator uint8_t(){
        return    ( this->b7 ? 0x80 : 0 ) | ( this->b6 ? 0x40 : 0 ) | (this->b5 ? 0x20 : 0) 
                | (this->b4 ? 0x10 :0) | ( this->b3 ? 0x08 : 0 ) | ( this->b2 ? 0x04 : 0 )
                | ( this->b1 ? 0x02 : 0 ) | (this->b0 ? 0x01 : 0);
    }
    operator int(){ return (int)(uint8_t)*this; }
};
```

*Structure delcaration file*

```cpp
//constants
#define bit0 0x1
#define bit1 0x2
#define bit2 0x4
#define bit3 0x8
#define nib  0xf
// pre-processor directives
#define toNib(val) (val&nib)
#define isBit(val,bit) (bool)( (val & bit) == bit )


//binary data display
/*
bin_data::bin_data( nabu n )
    :b0( isBit(n.mask,bit0) )
    ,b1( isBit(n.mask,bit1) )
    ,b2( isBit(n.mask,bit2) )
    ,b3( isBit(n.mask,bit3) )
    ,b4( isBit(n.mask,bit0) )
    ,b5( isBit(n.mask,bit1) )
    ,b6( isBit(n.mask,bit2) )
    ,b7( isBit(n.mask,bit3) ){}
*/
bin_data::bin_data( int val = 0 )
    :b0( isBit(val,bit0) ) ,b1( isBit(val,bit1) ) ,b2( isBit(val,bit2) ) ,b3( isBit(val,bit3) )
    ,b4( isBit(val, bit0 << 4 ) ) ,b5( isBit(val, bit1 << 4 ) ) ,b6( isBit(val, bit2 << 4 ) ) 
    ,b7( isBit(val, bit3 << 4 ) )
{ }
bin_data::bin_data( const bin_data &bdat )
    :b0(bdat.b0),b1(bdat.b1),b2(bdat.b2),b3(bdat.b3)
    ,b4(bdat.b4),b5(bdat.b5),b6(bdat.b6),b7(bdat.b7)
{ }
bin_data::bin_data( bin_data && bdat ){
    this->b0 = bdat.b0; bdat.b0 = 0;
    this->b1 = bdat.b1; bdat.b1 = 0;
    this->b2 = bdat.b2; bdat.b2 = 0;
    this->b3 = bdat.b3; bdat.b3 = 0;
    this->b4 = bdat.b4; bdat.b4 = 0;
    this->b5 = bdat.b5; bdat.b5 = 0;
    this->b6 = bdat.b6; bdat.b6 = 0;
    this->b7 = bdat.b7; bdat.b7 = 0; 
}

bin_data& bin_data::operator=( const bin_data &bdat ){
    this->b0 = bdat.b0; this->b1 = bdat.b1; this->b2 = bdat.b2; this->b3 = bdat.b3;
    this->b5 = bdat.b5; this->b6 = bdat.b6; this->b7 = bdat.b7; this->b4 = bdat.b4; 
    return *this;
}
bin_data& bin_data::operator=( bin_data && bdat ){
    this->b0 = bdat.b0; bdat.b0 = 0;
    this->b1 = bdat.b1; bdat.b1 = 0;
    this->b2 = bdat.b2; bdat.b2 = 0;
    this->b3 = bdat.b3; bdat.b3 = 0;
    this->b4 = bdat.b4; bdat.b4 = 0;
    this->b5 = bdat.b5; bdat.b5 = 0;
    this->b6 = bdat.b6; bdat.b6 = 0;
    this->b7 = bdat.b7; bdat.b7 = 0; 
    return *this;
}

bin_data::~bin_data(){ }

std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream& os, const bin_data &bdat ){
    return os   << bdat.b7 << bdat.b6 << bdat.b5 << bdat.b4 << '-' 
                << bdat.b3 << bdat.b2 << bdat.b1 << bdat.b0;
}
```

**Disclaimer: I need to use `bit fields` since some part of my program depends on unorthodox `bitwise` manipulation (outside of traditional logic gates), and it makes it easier to check what happened.**

Thank you for your time.

### Edit

Since **unorthodox `bitwise` manipulation (outside of traditional logic gates)** seems so vague as pointed out by comments. Here are some of the functions I am implementing on this structure, and therefore why I need access to individual bits.

**Unit set - defining presence**

`C = A*B` - tipical and gate representation

**Undefined A set - directional logic**

`C = A - A*B` - determines if objects don't generate 1D logic space, which object is present.

**Undefined B set - directional logic**

`C = B - A*B` - same as Undef A , but oposite set

**Null Set - aka object isnt present**

`C = 1 - (A+B) + (A*B)` - determines failure to establish 1D logic space

Comment: Have you unit tested this code and does it work?

Comment: Unit tested, no. I don't know how. But I did test each part of it, and it works. And it drives half of my project so far without an glitch. But I did have an experience when code that works great suddenly after 500 lines of code starts bugging out. I credit this to my lack of knowledge.

Comment: I have modified the title to make it fit within the rules of Code Review. Questions in the tile like `are there any bugs` could indicate that the question is off-topic due to non-working code. Good reviewers will let you know about the bugs anyway.

Comment: @pacmaninbw thank you! I see it is automatically accepted. I was having real trouble with the tittle. Didn't know how to format it as a question.

Comment: I think you've just reinvented `std::bitset<8>` - perhaps most of your code isn't necessary?

Comment: @TobySpeight , yeah. I did. But as mentioned I am using non traditional logic bitwise manipulations. So I need to acces individual bits, `std::bitset` result is an accidental plus.

Comment: @Danilo can you add an explicit example of what you need and cannot do with std::bitset? Nor the disclaimer, nor your comment make it any clearer...

Comment: When you get above 2000 reputation your edits should always be accepted.

Comment: @slepic I added formulas. Null set is like NOT OR, and Unit Set is like AND, but most of my code relies on undefined states.

Comment: `I need access to individual bits`. And bitset has that. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/operator_at
Also If I understand what you mean by `*`,`-` and `+`, then `A*B` is just `A & B` , `A-B` is just `A & ~B`, `A + B` is `A | B`. I still dont see your problem impossible or difficult to implement with bitset. Also i dont understand what relying on undefined states mean.

Comment: @slepic , AxB is A&B but the rest isn't. When i said like *such gate*  I ment truth table is similar, not operation.

Comment: I give up, dude. You should add `reinventing-the-wheel` tag to this question. Anyway, good luck.

Comment: Not cool dude. Not cool at all. Tone and public annunciation was unnecessary and rude.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Avoid Using the `this` Pointer

It is very rare to see the `this` pointer used in c++ code, it generally isn't necessary. The code in this question compiles fine without the this pointer. Consider making the structure into a class.

### Avoid Using Macros in C++

In C++ it is better to use constexpr `TYPE SYMBOL = constant;` because it allows the compiler to do type checking when the values are used.

```
constexpr unsigned bit0 = 0x1;
constexpr unsigned bit1 = 0x1 << 1;
constexpr unsigned bit2 = 0x1 << 2;
constexpr unsigned bit3 = 0x1 << 3;
constexpr unsigned nib = 0xf;
```

Instead of macro functions use inline functions.

```
bool isBit(unsigned val, unsigned bit) { static_cast<bool> ((val & bit) == bit); }
```

It might be better to replace bool with unsigned as the underlying storage type, many programmers that program hardware and need to toggle bits will use unsigned.

### The Default Constructor

In the header file there is this constructor `bin_data(int);` and in the cpp file there is

```
bin_data::bin_data( int val = 0 )
    :b0( isBit(val,bit0) ) ,b1( isBit(val,bit1) ) ,b2( isBit(val,bit2) ) ,b3( isBit(val,bit3) )
    ,b4( isBit(val, bit0 << 4 ) ) ,b5( isBit(val, bit1 << 4 ) ) ,b6( isBit(val, bit2 << 4 ) ) 
    ,b7( isBit(val, bit3 << 4 ) )
{ }
```

My compiler (Visual Studio 2019) complains about this portion of the constructor in the cpp file:

```
bin_data::bin_data( int val = 0 )
```

It would probably be better if the code in the header file was `bin_data(int val = 0);` otherwise another constructor needs to be written which does not accept an `int` as input, remove the `int val = 0` in the cpp file.

```
bin_data::bin_data(int val)
    :b0( isBit(val,bit0) ) ,b1( isBit(val,bit1) ) ,b2( isBit(val,bit2) ) ,b3( isBit(val,bit3) )
    ,b4( isBit(val, bit0 << 4 ) ) ,b5( isBit(val, bit1 << 4 ) ) ,b6( isBit(val, bit2 << 4 ) ) 
    ,b7( isBit(val, bit3 << 4 ) )
{ }
```

*Note, the comma operator should always be followed by a space.*

### Use C++ Casts Rather Than Old C Style Casts

There are old C style casts in several places, it is better to use either `static_cast<type>` or `dynamic_cast<type>` in C++. In this code they would all be static_cast.

Current code

```
#define isBit(val,bit) (bool)( (val & bit) == bit )
```

more modern code

```
bool isBit(unsigned val, unsigned bit) { static_cast<bool> ((val & bit) == bit); }
```

Comment: What are benefits of class against structure in this example?  
  
I used  `bin_data::bin_data(int val = 0)` to replace an empty initialisation - as an shorthand. I could remedy that.  
  
What makes new c++ casts better than what I normally use? Is that some sort of code ethics thing or there is added benefit?

Comment: If you put the bin_data(int val = 0) into the header the empty initialization still works. static_cast provides additional type checking.

Comment: I just need to mention that `isBit` in form you supplied doesn't work for me unless I put an return statement.

Comment: @Danilo Sorry, it does need that return.

Answer (score 4):

A few observations, additional to the [review by pacmaninbw](/a/232263).

Headers: `<iostream>` isn't needed for the header, but is needed for the code.  We probably want to declare that `operator<<()` in the header, though - for which we should include `<iosfwd>`.  We also need `<cstdint>`, to declare `std::uint8_t`.

The converting constructor from `int` is a narrowing conversion, so we really ought to make that `explicit`.

The move constructor and move assignment operators don't add any value, unless there's a demonstrated need to zero the source.  I believe they should be omitted.

The destructor adds no value at all, and should be omitted.

Conversion to `bool` isn't necessary, as there's a conversion to `int`, and `int` implicitly converts to `bool`.

Conversion to `std::uint8_t` could be simplified:

```
operator std::uint8_t()
{
    return 0x80 * b7 + 0x40 * b6 + 0x20 * b5 + 0x10 * b4
        +  0x08 * b3 + 0x04 * b2 + 0x02 * b1 + 0x01 * b0;
}
```

The streaming operator will produce different results depending on whether the stream has `std::boolalpha` set or not.  Is that desirable?